# laravel @error('name') {{$message}}

Tags: php, laravel

Есть форма, в которой делаю валидацию данных:

```
@extends('html')

@section('title', 'create')
@section('content')

    <h1>Create service</h1>
    <form action='/service' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='name'>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button>Add service</button>
    </form>
    @error('name') {{ $message }} @enderror

@endsection
```

Вот метод, обрабатывающий запрос

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $data = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);
        $var = request('name');
        DB::table('services')->insert(['name' => $var]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

При попытке зайти на страницу с формой выдаёт такую ошибку:

> ErrorException Undefined variable: message

Comment: ошибки быть не должно, попробуйте сбросить кэш `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Ошибка - Could not open input file: artisan

Comment: а если перед этим cd в директорию с laravel?

Comment: кэш почистился, но ошибка всё равно осталась

Comment: а у меня работает ваш пример https://ibb.co/6NSSQxb

Comment: может с компьютером что-то, я использую openserver

Comment: через `echo phpinfo();` посмотрите подключенные модули php и сверьте с требованиями laravel к модулям

Comment: нашёл ответ, так надо писать: foreach ($errors->all() as $error) <p>{{ $error }}</p>                     endforeach

Comment: вынесите это в ответ, вдруг кто еще с этим столкнется

Answer (score 0):

```
нашёл ответ, так надо писать: foreach ($errors->all() as $error) <p>{{ $error }}</p> endforeach
```